# myDB.execute hangs the application when updating SharePoint list

Tags: vba, sharepoint, dao

I am running this script in an Outlook application. It will analyze emails, forward to the appropriate team, move the received email to a "processed" folder, etc...
Now for the next step, I want to log the movements to our SharePoint.

I have added a few lines of code, and it worked as a charm in my (company provided) computer.

What I added is basically:

```
Dim db as Database
Set db = DAO.OpenDatabase("path\thedb.accdb")
db.execute(myquery)
```

The query is always an insert. I have tried the full insert with the variables in it, or just something like this

```
db.Execute "INSERT INTO the_list ([tktnum]) VALUES ('987654');"
```

I have searched and the only thing that gave me hope is to add `dbFailOnError`, as in

```
db.Execute "INSERT INTO the_list ([tktnum]) VALUES ('987654');", dbFailOnError
```

but it made no difference.

and again: from my computer, it runs perfectly.

Now, if I go to the server where the script is running and add the SharePoint update code, it will crash Outlook. With a breakpoint on the `db.execute` line, I see that Outlook stays [running] for about 5 seconds, then it crashes. I have left it there, working other things, and came back hours later and it was still hung.

- I have 2 servers I can use for this, which are in a dedicated datacenter zone. Error happens in both.
- They are in the same subnet.
- Both are 2008R2, I have installed Office 2013 Pro.
- One server is connected to the company KMS while the other has the firewall rule pending for it, so Office shows unlicensed in the latter.
- I can browse the SharePoint from both servers, I actually had to in order to click "Open with Access" in IE, which would download the accdb file I am opening with the OpenDatabase method.
- Currently, a local user runs the script. I have logged on with the application ID domain\my.team.name, configured Outlook in this session, error continues.

  - This ID has permissions over the SharePoint site and list.

I am clueless. If anyone knows if there are more ports other than 443 that this uses, I can request any policies to be created.

Thanks for reading, hope you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that instead of using DAO, by using ADO I can successfully update the sharepoint list from the server.